# Can I define a method as an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

The topic above is a bit ambiguous, the explaination is below:

```py
class Trainer:
    """Object used to facilitate training."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        # params: Namespace,
        params,
        model,
        device=torch.device("cpu"),
        optimizer=None,
        scheduler=None,
        wandb_run=None,
        early_stopping: callbacks.EarlyStopping = None,
    ):
        # Set params
        self.params = params
        self.model = model
        self.device = device

        # self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.optimizer = self.get_optimizer()
        self.scheduler = scheduler
        self.wandb_run = wandb_run
        self.early_stopping = early_stopping

        # list to contain various train metrics
        # TODO: how to add more metrics? wandb log too. Maybe save to model artifacts?

        self.history = DefaultDict(list)

    @staticmethod
    def get_optimizer(
        model: models.CustomNeuralNet,
        optimizer_params: global_params.OptimizerParams(),
    ):
        """Get the optimizer for the model.

        Args:
            model (models.CustomNeuralNet): [description]
            optimizer_params (global_params.OptimizerParams): [description]

        Returns:
            [type]: [description]
        """
        return getattr(torch.optim, optimizer_params.optimizer_name)(
            model.parameters(), **optimizer_params.optimizer_params
        )
```

Notice that initially I passed in `optimizer` in the constructor, where I will be calling it outside this class. However, I now put `get_optimizer` inside the class itself (for consistency purpose, but unsure if it is ok). So, should I still define `self.optimizer = self.get_optimizer()` or just use `self.get_optimizer()` at the designated places in the class? The former encourages some readability for me.

---

Addendum: I now put the instance inside the `.fit()` method where I will call say 5 times to train the model 5 times. In this scenario, even though there won't be any obvious issue as we are using optimizer once per call, will it still be better to not define `self.optimizer` here?

```py
    def fit(
        self,
        train_loader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader,
        valid_loader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader,
        fold: int = None,
    ):
        """[summary]

        Args:
            train_loader (torch.utils.data.DataLoader): [description]
            val_loader (torch.utils.data.DataLoader): [description]
            fold (int, optional): [description]. Defaults to None.

        Returns:
            [type]: [description]
        """
        self.optimizer = self.get_optimizer(
            model=self.model, optimizer_params=OPTIMIZER_PARAMS
        )
        self.scheduler = self.get_scheduler(
            optimizer=self.optimizer, scheduler_params=SCHEDULER_PARAMS
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between the two: calling your `get_optimizer` will instantiate a *new* `torch.optim.<optimizer>` every time. In contrast, setting `self.optimizer` and accessing it numerous times later will only create a *single* optimizer instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I added an addendum, on whether I should/nt do this.

Comment: @ilovewt in that case, `get_optimizer` should be "ptivate" and be called only inside the `__init__`

Comment: Thank you! One last question, since `get_optimizer` does not invoke self, I turned it into a static method. I should still call `self.optimizer = self.get_optimizer()` under init right?